# Show that $x|y \Rightarrow x \leq y$

Tags: induction

I have to show that $x|y \Rightarrow x \leq y$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{N} \land x,y \neq 0$

Can someone give me a start hint how I can show this? I guess I can proof by induction. Not quite sure where to start

$x|y \Leftrightarrow xn =y$

Comment: $\Rightarrow n=\frac{y}{x}\geq1 \Rightarrow y\geq x$ given your definition for x|y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y-x=xn-x=x\left(n-1\right)\geq0$

(Here $x,y\in\mathbb{N}\wedge x,y\neq0\wedge n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $y=xn$
can only be true if $n$ is a positive integer.)

Comment: This looks pretty complete. Probably I need to specify that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \ge 1$

Comment: Yes. For that have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 4):

You want to show that $nx\geq x$. This is simply the inequality $n\geq1$ multiplied on both sides by $x$.